# CSS3 column-span property does not supported in Safari. Why?

Tags: css, safari

I need to flow my text in two columns.

CSS3 is't fully implemented by all browsers, and i expected, that this property is called

```
-webkit-column-span: all
```

But, i faced a little problem - Safari 5 does not supports this feature ?

I think, some reason should exists, why Apple has dropped this feature ...

Maybe they are some alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did Apple dropped this feature?

`column-all` [was supported in WebKit since June 1st](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15550) at r60494. Safari 5 was released in June 7th. I don't think 6 days is enough to push trunk code to release build for these large scale projects. So, this would be supported, but probably in next minor version.

If that span-all element is at the beginning or the end of the text, you could just put it *outside* of the column-styled tag.